# How to display data from Core Data database in custom TableView Cells?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, cell

I want to display data from a searchable Core Data database in custom TableView Cells, which consist of a small image, title label, and price label. How do I go about doing this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually quite a lot that goes into it. First you need to use a custom table view and some custom cells. Then in the custom cell code you can set the data for various labels and field. This is usually done by passing the cell an object, the cell reads the object and populates the data.

I used this sample code to get started in a similar project, the only difference being we parsed our data from xml instead of getting it from core data. This code will show you how to populate the cells, I think it reads it from a static plist but you should be able to modify it to suit your needs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139

Comment: Will this work efficiently when listing 1000+ items in the TableView?

Comment: I don't know to be honest. For our purposes it was less than 100. The code is pretty straight forward, no glaring inefficiencies that I could  tell and seems to work optimally with the iOS system. It was written by  Apple after all so it should work reasonably well. Limitations here might be the computing power of the phone. It's worth a shot.

Comment: 1000+ items seems, not very user friendly. Might want to split it up into pages or by some category.

Comment: I will split these items into categories. However, users will not be scrolling through the listings but most of the time using the search functionality.

Comment: You'll still want to set some sort of limit for items per page for that search functionality, categories too. I don't think directly drawing 1000+ items on a smart phone screen will ever be a good idea.